# Java getContentPane().setBackground() not working

Tags: java, swing

Im trying to encapsulate the GUI calls to a single class. My window appears but the background remains the default color instead of red.

ChatProgram.java

```
package ChatPkg;

public class ChatProgram {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ChatWindow.initialize();
        ChatWindow.RunWindow();

    }

}
```

ChatWindow.java

```
package ChatPkg;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

public final class ChatWindow {

    static JFrame frame;

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    private ChatWindow() { }

    public static void RunWindow() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    public static void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("Chat program");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 450);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JCheckBox chckbxCvbc = new JCheckBox("cvbc");
        frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxCvbc);

        // Set background color
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
    }

}
```

Yes i am new to Java and none of the google results solved my problem.

Comment: I am guessing it should `RED` and not `red`. That's usually how constants are typed - but it is just a guess.

Comment: @Gendarme it's a lousy guess. It would not compile if the field was not present. Which it is.

Comment: @Gendarme there is both uppercase and lowercase

Comment: This program is problematic in a number of ways but it does put up a red Jframe for me (Java 8, OS X). Can you add some more details to your question about how and where you are running it and what output you get?

Comment: @pvg sorry i deleted these lines from the question because i thought they were innocent. I deleted "JCheckBox chckbxCvbc = new JCheckBox("cvbc"); frame.getContentPane().add(chckbxCvbc);" before i call setBackground(). Its as if creating a simple checkbox overwrote the background color, why is this?

Comment: Can you restore the lines in the question please? Hard to read in comments.

Comment: No problem, there you go:) @pvg

Comment: Well, it still works for me. What version of Java are you running and what OS? I think generally, I recommend you go through the Java tutorial and Java Swing tutorials from Oracle. This is not how you write a Java or Swing program and if you keep writing like that, you'll wade into an ever deeper ocean of pain. even this "Im trying to encapsulate the GUI calls to a single class." is a terrible idea. The tutorials have extensive worked examples you can use as a starting point for your own work.

Answer (score 1):

You should **NOT** add GUI components directly to the content pane of the `JFrame`. Also, you shouldn't modify its properties (like you tried changing the background).

You always need a `JPanel` that acts as a container on which the graphical elements are added. Here is how you could write your initialize function:

```
public static void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame("Chat program");
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 450);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    JCheckBox chckbxCvbc = new JCheckBox("cvbc");
    panel.add(chckbxCvbc);

    // Set background color and add panel to the Jframe
    panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
}
```